# Upgrading React from 15.1 to 16.13.1 (and other packages) and this.props is undefined. How was it working before and what do I change now?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-proptypes

I'm working on a React app that is using 15.1. We want to do a better job of keeping things up to date so I'm trying to move to the latest (16.13.1). My experience with React is still somewhat limited. Here is a representative sample of what I'm working with.

> NamesView.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { nameActions } from 'redux/modules/names'
import NamesPanel from 'containers/NamesPanel'

export class NamesView extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    reportActions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { nameActions } = this.props
    nameActions.getNames()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <NamesPanel />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    nameActions: bindActionCreators(nameActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NamesView)
```

> NamesPanel.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap'
import NamesTable from 'components/NamesTable'

export class NamesPanel extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Panel defaultExpanded collapsible header='Names'>
        <NamesTable />
      </Panel>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NamesPanel)
```

> NamesTable.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap'

export const fields = []

const validate = (values, props) => {
  const errors = {}
  return errors
}

export class NamesTable extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object,
    names: PropTypes.array,
    valid: PropTypes.bool,
    dirty: PropTypes.bool,
    touchAll: PropTypes.func
  }

  render () {
    const { names } = this.props

    return (
      <Table striped bordered>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Last</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {names.map((name, index) => {
            return (   
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{name.first}</td>
              <td>{name.last}</td>
            </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    names: state.names,
    initialValues: {
      names: state.names
    }
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'NamesTable',
  fields,
  validate,
  touchOnChange: false
}, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NamesTable)
```

I pretty much upgraded everything and I know there are changes to proptypes - it had been using that from React instead of prop-types. When I run it now `this.props` is undefined in the `render` method of `NamesTable.js`. It's obviously not being passed down from the `NamesPanel.js`. The api is being called in `NamesView.js`.

I guess my question is, if you'll excuse my ignorance, how was that working before? And what do I need to change to make it work now?

Feel like this is something obvious and I'm not 100% sure what to search for.

---

Thanks to maten's help I changed this bit in `NamesTable.js`.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'NamesTable',
  fields,
  validate,
  touchOnChange: false
})(NamesTable))
```

Seems to be working now.

Comment: Those props weren't coming from the parent component, but from the redux store:```mapStateToProps``` should inject them.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Any pointers on where to look to see where it's failing now?

Comment: it seems like you still need to use the ```connect``` HOC with redux-forms, check this out: https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/faq/howtoconnect.md/

Comment: @maten - You're a lifesaver! That was just the push I needed. It looks like my page is loading now. Now to test on some additional pages and get the things I broke along the way fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible because of react and react-dom version miss-match so, Please upgrade react-dom.

This is the way you can upgrade your react-dom:

```
npm install react-dom@^16.13.1
```